# How to extract repetitive text ifrom text file using python regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have to extract text from a text file having.

Reg.No.________ xajh sak  ska  ajs kajk  sak Reg.No.________ 
sasa  as a a sa sa dad Reg.No.________  adad

```
 y=re.findall(r'(?=(Reg.No.________[^Reg.No.________]*Reg.No.________))',te, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Output should be like this:

list[0]=Reg.No.________ xajh sak  ska  ajs kajk  sak

list[1]=Reg.No.________ sasa  as a a sa sa dad

list[2]=Reg.No.________  adad

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: y=re.findall(r'(Reg.+?)Reg',te, flags=re.DOTALL)

Comment: I tried this but it's not working properly it's skipping some patterns

Comment: You can match ` Reg\.No\.` (note the space at the beginning) and replace with `\nReg.No.` to arrange the entries vertically.  However, there is no way with pure regex to include the incrementing count that you have at the beginning of each line inside `list[#]`. https://regex101.com/r/aStQ7L/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
Reg.+?(?=Reg|$)
```

that will *match* the strings you need. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SPKeSb/1).

[Same pattern](https://regex101.com/r/SPKeSb/2), but unrolled acc. to unroll-the-loop principle (thus, faster):

```
Reg[^R]*(?:R(?!eg)[^R]*)*
```

**Details**

- `Reg` - a `Reg` substring
- `.+?` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=Reg|$)` - `Reg` substring or end of string.

Note that to only match `Reg` as a whole word, you may add `\b` word boundary before it.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/RPGgNo):

```
import re
rx = r"Reg.+?(?=Reg|$)"
s = "Reg.No.________ xajh sak ska ajs kajk sak Reg.No.________ sasa as a a sa sa dad Reg.No.________ adad"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['Reg.No.________ xajh sak ska ajs kajk sak ', 'Reg.No.________ sasa as a a sa sa dad ', 'Reg.No.________ adad']
```

Note you may later `strip()` the resulting strings.

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver